# How to deploy react app subdirectory with BrowserRouter?

Tags: reactjs, apache, deployment

I have a React App (CRA) who is currently deployed on HTTP Apache Server. To access to the app I use the url root (http:///). Because of adding supplementary apps I have to specify the app name in the url to access it. Like that http:///
To do that I tried to set the homepage in package.json with

```
 "homepage": "http://<ip>/<folder_name>",
```

I also set the basename of my Router in my React Component with the folder name.

```
  <BrowserRouter basename="/<folder_name>">
```

After these modifications when I try to access to the site I have a blank page. And in the console I get two erros.

> stylesheet http://localhost:3000/src/css/component.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”
>
> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' main.xxx.js

My project is under /var/www/html/.
I also create a htaccess in the react public folder.

If any has an idea I'll be thankful.

Thanks