# React app subdir deploy static files issue

Tags: reactjs, deployment, static

I need to deploy React app behind httpd proxy and I'm having issues with static files. The app must be deployed at https://example.com/app1.

When I visit the homepage of the app the HTML contains this script:

```
<script defer src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

...which is not correct as the script is located here:

```
https://example.com/app1/static/js/bundle.js
```

After some research I stumbled upon this question: [React app is looking for static files in different location when using proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423575/react-app-is-looking-for-static-files-in-different-location-when-using-proxy)

It's exactly the same problem I have, but the solution doesn't work for me.

I've tried to add this into package.json:

```
"homepage": "https://example.com/app1",
```

And in this case generated script tag in HTML is actually correct:

```
<script defer src="/app1/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

...but now for some reason the static file is not located here and I get some default React HTML which leads to javascript error as '<' means syntax error in javascript. I get same behavior for all static files.

I'm almost sure this question is also related, but has no answers: [How to deploy react app subdirectory with BrowserRouter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065089/how-to-deploy-react-app-subdirectory-with-browserrouter)